# Docker + Webpack (Dev Server) + Yarnpkg incomplete builds

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, webpack-dev-server, yarnpkg

## Problem

Converting a `webpack` project that runs locally right now to run inside `docker` containers. This work takes place in two `git` branches: `develop`, and `containers`.

## Local (No Container)

`develop` is the stable base, which runs locally via
`$ yarn install && npm run dev` given the following in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node .",
    "env:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development",
    "env:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production",
    "predev": "npm run prebuild",
    "dev": "npm run env:dev -- webpack-dev-server",
//[...]
}
```

The branch `develop` does include `yarn.lock`, though FWIW, `$ rm yarn.lock && yarn install --force && npm run dev` does start up the server correctly, i.e. `GET http://localhost:3000` gives me the homepage, as I expect to see it. The above all works the same after `$ git checkout containers`

## Docker

After shutting down the local dev server, I run `$ git checkout containers`, and this branch does NOT contain the `yarn.lock` or `package.lock`. I then run `$ docker-compose up --build web` (in a separate terminal, in a sibling directory that contains the following in the `docker-compose.yaml`)

```
   web:
      build:
       context: ../frontend/
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
      env_file: ../frontend/.env
      volumes:
        - ../frontend/src:/code/src
      ports:
        - "3001:3000"
      depends_on:
        - api
      networks:
        - backend
```

The `frontend/Dockerfile` for the service `web` is like so

```
# Dockerfile

FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir /code
ADD . /code/
WORKDIR /code/
RUN yarn cache clean && yarn install --non-interactive --force && npm rebuild node-sass

CMD npm run dev --verbose
```

given

```
#frontend/.dockerignore

node_modules
deploy
.circleci
stories
.storybook
```

All *seems* to go well, and the final line of the startup is `web_1         | Server is running at http://localhost:3000/.` 
Yet when I `GET http://localhost:3001` (note port mapping in `docker-compose`), the page that's returned does not contain the expected `<style>...</style>` tag in the `<head>` as is supposed to be injected (as far as I understand) by `webpack`, given the configuration below

```
// https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/wiki/Webpack
const path = require('path')
const devServer = require('@webpack-blocks/dev-server2')
const splitVendor = require('webpack-blocks-split-vendor')
const happypack = require('webpack-blocks-happypack')
const serverSourceMap = require('webpack-blocks-server-source-map')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const AssetsByTypePlugin = require('webpack-assets-by-type-plugin')
const ChildConfigPlugin = require('webpack-child-config-plugin')
const SpawnPlugin = require('webpack-spawn-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

const {
  addPlugins, createConfig, entryPoint, env, setOutput,
  sourceMaps, defineConstants, webpack, group,
} = require('@webpack-blocks/webpack2')

const host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost'
const port = (+process.env.PORT + 1) || 3001
const sourceDir = process.env.SOURCE || 'src'
const publicPath = `/${process.env.PUBLIC_PATH || ''}/`.replace('//', '/')
const sourcePath = path.join(process.cwd(), sourceDir)
const outputPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist/public')
const assetsPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist/assets.json')
const clientEntryPath = path.join(sourcePath, 'client.js')
const serverEntryPath = path.join(sourcePath, 'server.js')
const devDomain = `http://${host}:${port}/`

//[...]  
const sass = () => () => ({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        use: [
            { loader: 'style-loader' },
            { loader: 'css-loader' },
            { loader: 'sass-loader'},
            ],
      },
    ],
  },
})

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'style.css',
})

const prodSass = () => () => ({
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        use: extractSass.extract({
          use: [
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } },
            { loader: 'sass-loader' },
          ],
          fallback: 'style-loader',
        }),
      },
    ],
  },
})

const babel = () => () => ({
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
    ],
  },
})

const assets = () => () => ({
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8000' },
    ],
  },
})

const resolveModules = modules => () => ({
  resolve: {
    modules: [].concat(modules, ['node_modules']),
  },
})

const base = () => group([
  setOutput({
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: outputPath,
    publicPath,
  }),
  defineConstants({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': process.env.NODE_ENV,
    'process.env.PUBLIC_PATH': publicPath.replace(/\/$/, ''),
  }),
  addPlugins([
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
    extractSass,
  ]),
  apiInsert(),
  happypack([
    babel(),
  ]),
  assets(),
  resolveModules(sourceDir),

  env('development', [
    setOutput({
      publicPath: devDomain,
    }),
    sass(),
  ]),

  env('production', [
    prodSass(),
  ]),
])

const server = createConfig([
  base(),
  entryPoint({ server: serverEntryPath }),
  setOutput({
    filename: '../[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  }),
  addPlugins([
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: 'global.assets = require("./assets.json");',
      raw: true,
    }),
  ]),
  () => ({
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    stats: 'errors-only',
  }),

  env('development', [
    serverSourceMap(),
    addPlugins([
      new SpawnPlugin('npm', ['start']),
    ]),
    () => ({
      watch: true,
    }),
  ]),
])

const client = createConfig([
  base(),
  entryPoint({ client: clientEntryPath }),
  addPlugins([
    new AssetsByTypePlugin({ path: assetsPath }),
    new ChildConfigPlugin(server),
  ]),

  env('development', [
    devServer({
      contentBase: 'public',
      stats: 'errors-only',
      historyApiFallback: { index: publicPath },
      headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
      host,
      port,
    }),
    sourceMaps(),
    addPlugins([
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    ]),
  ]),

  env('production', [
    splitVendor(),
    addPlugins([
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false } }),
    ]),
  ]),
])

module.exports = client
```

Interestingly, adding this line to `package.json`

```
 "dev-docker": "npm run predev && npm run env:dev -- webpack  --progress --watch --watch-poll",
```

and changing the last line of the Dockerfile to `CMD npm run dev-docker` does yield the desired effect...

## Hypotheses

My current suspicion is that I am missing something about how the webpack dev server handles serving its loader output, and have not mapped some port properly, but that's a shot in the dark.

Alternatively, the `webpack-dev-server` version is a problem. Local is `4.4.2` where docker's shows `5.6.0`, though this seems probably not the issue as the documentation for latest matches my own setup. I've confirmed that the `package.json` specification for the loader modules is the latest stable on each of them.

## Apologia

Recognizing that this is a problem caused by the intersection of several technologies in a config-dependent and necessarily idiosyncratic way, I humbly ask your help in working through this dependency hell. If it seems like I do not understand how a given piece of the puzzle operates, I'm happy to hear it. Any ideas, leads, or suggestions, however tenuous, will be greatly appreciated and exploited to the best of my abilities.

Comment: Your problem seems to be `volumes:        - ../frontend/src:/code/src`, Your are overwriting the built data with your local. Can you remove that and try if it works?

Comment: that does make sense, but removing that entry doesn't seem to have any effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while, but coming back to this problem, I found the actual answer.

The `webpack-dev-server` uses two ports. Thus, in exposing only the one port (3000) I was not getting the built files, which are served in `client.js` on `localhost:3001`. The clue was right there the whole time in the JS console: a connection refused error on `GET localhost:3001/client.js`.

The solution is to expose both ports on the container, i.e.
`docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 --rm --entrypoint "npm run env:dev -- webpack-dev-server" ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}`

Answer (score 5):

Long shot here, but I was trying to run a grails-vue app in docker containers and had issues with the port mappings of webpack-dev-server not being exposed properly.

I found this issue on github https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/547 which led to me adding --host 0.0.0.0 to my dev task in package.json like so:

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0"
```

This solved my problem, maybe this will help you find your answer.

Comment: Thank you! This issue has gotten me in many different contexts when working with Linux. Whenever your dealing with localhost, always gotta set the hosting IP to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that your locally installed packages differ from the packages in the docker container.

To be sure that you have the same packages installed, you should include `yarn.lock` and `package.lock` files. If you only use yarn `yarn.lock` should suffice. Even if this does not solve your specific problem, it can prevent others, because now you have a deterministic build.

Comment: To clarify, the behavior is the same with or without the lock files.

Comment: Then it could be the webpack-dev-server version. You should make sure that everything has the same version number, to eliminate this as the cause for the different behavior.